# Xcode linker command failed with exit code 1

Tags: xcode, swift, sprite-kit

I'm having an annoying problem with Xcode. I can't run the projects and it gives me back the same error every time:

> ld: file not found: /Users/DagDigg/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Roundy2-dtzcccrlvjvoxsapfbdzchhtuivr/Build/Intermediates/Roundy2.build/Debug-iphoneos/Roundy2.build/Objects-normal/arm64/AppDelegate.o
>
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I'm unable to run every project. Even if I create an empty one...

I'm using Xcode 7 beta 3 and an iPhone with iOS 9 beta 4.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sometimes it's helpful to quit Xcode and erase the files in your DeriveData folder at

```
~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
```

Answer (score 0):

I've also fixed this issue by going to Product -> Clean in XCode. This might erase the files in the files in the Derived Data folder in the process.

Answer (score 0):

Clean build folder + Rebuild the project worked for me.

Step 1: **product -> Clean Build Folder**

Step 2: **product -> Build**

Answer (score 0):

Maybe double-check the `Xcode` file you are running. Close the `Xcode` project then be sure to open the `<projectname>.xcworkspace` file.

If you are using `cocoapods`, the error can be from trying to build from the `.xcodeproj` file instead of the `.xcworkspace` file generated by the pod install.

---

"Open the `MyApp.xcworkspace` that was created. This should be the file you use everyday to create your app." - [guides.cocoapods.org/using/using-cocoapods](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/using-cocoapods.html)

Answer (score -1):

Usualy this issue occur while you run your project on simulator devices ,
and simply you can remove DerivedData folder to pass this

But i suggest you to use real devices