# clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 when archiving

Tags: ios, xcode

I am receiving an error when trying to archive my app - The simulator and iPhone work fine running the project.

```
ld: framework not found Pods_NameofAPP
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have seen on other stack overflow posts to disable BitCode. That had no effect. Other questions suggest I should add Pods_SharkMate as a linked framework however I does not show as an option. Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31592670/xcode-linker-command-failed-with-exit-code-1

Comment: Is this the first time you have done a build?

Comment: @George_E I have deleted all DerivedData and it is the first time I am archiving the app

Answer (score 1):

Removing pod_NameOFApp from frameworks solved it for me

Answer (score 0):

Click on your project in the **Project Navigator**. Make sure you are on **Target**, and go to where it shows your **Developer Team**. Click **Add Account**, or re-type password. This should work.

Any problems/changes/simplification needed, just message me.

Comment: @HoovinShmoovin That's what the problem was for me... are you using the developer provisional license?      Also consider doing what Md Rashed Pervez said, by cleaning the project.

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple steps -

1. Press `shift + alt + cmd + k` . (to clean your project)
2. Then press `cmd + shift + B` (to build your project)

This will remove the error from your project. If needed try the `step one` more than one time. Hope this will solve your problem.